# MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have my docker-compose orchestration and I'm getting this error:

`connection error: { MongoError: failed to connect to server [172.17.0.2:27018] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.2:27018]`

This is the code in `server.js`:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodb:27018');
```

This happen only when I customize the `command` of my docker container:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./my-node-app
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.5
    command: mongod --port 27018
```

If I remove the `--port 27018` and point to the default `27017` the error gets fixed.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You're missing: --bind_ip_all

It seems that [newer](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/commit/b380604c031e2e13884538fead9780ea77ce2b59) versions (>3.5) of the `mongod` daemon listen only to localhost by default.

Your are overriding [this](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/45055cc0c67da614a3edf24369fb1484701f88e3/3.5/Dockerfile#L70):

```
CMD ["mongod", "--bind_ip_all"]
```

So, also put `"--bind_ip_all"` in your docker-compose.yml:

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo:3.5
  command: mongod --port 27018 --bind_ip_all
```